# Angular 2 validation on click

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i m pretty new on angular2. I m using ng2-bootstrap tab and i need to check the some fields in each tabs. I m googling this and i always find the answer with form validation instead of validation with click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add your codes please :)

Comment: Sry for dealy replay , I have html form i have added 4 text fields and button and in component i have created a function on this function i need to add validation like jquery .

Comment: attach your code to the question. how we can suggest a solution without seeing your code